# Does a client get charged per listener for the same Firestore query?

Tags: google-cloud-firestore

I am listening to real time updates to Firestore by registering onSnapshot listeners. If I register two listeners for the same query (the listeners have different processing logic), will I be charged twice as much? I am aware I could combine the logic or emit another CustomEvent with the data they could consume instead if that is the case - just wondering what the consequences of doing it this way would be.

e.g.

```
  db.collection("cities").doc("SF")
    .onSnapshot(function(doc) {
        console.log("Current data: ", doc.data());
        // Process A
    });
  db.collection("cities").doc("SF")
    .onSnapshot(function(doc) {
        console.log("Current data: ", doc.data());
        // Process B
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes. As far as I'm aware, you are charged per reading of any document.

Edit: Removed portion of concurrent connections, I seem to have interpreted it differently

Comment: What you're saying isn't true about number of connections.  Each client app instance only ever makes a single connection to the database, even if there are multiple listeners.  All queries and results are pipelined over that one connection. This is the case for both Realtime Database and Firestore.

Comment: I see, so the concurrent connections are the number of app instances connected?

Comment: In simple terms, it's the number of socket connections currently open from running apps.

Comment: sorry confused - is this correct about listeners?

Comment: @DougStevenson ^