# How to subscribe to an entire collection and a document within it simultaneously without duplicating the amount of reads?

Tags: flutter, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I am writing for learning purposes a cross-platform to-do app with Flutter and Firestore. Currently, I have the following design, and I would like to know if there are better alternatives.

One of the main screens of the app shows a list of all tasks. It does this by subscribing to the corresponding Firestore collection, which we'll say is `/tasks` for simplicity.

```dart
FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection("tasks").snapshots()
```

Each tile in the ListView of tasks can be clicked. Clicking a tile opens a new screen (with `Navigator.push`) showing details about that specific task.

**Importantly, this screen also needs to update in real-time**, so it is not enough to just pass it the (local, immutable) task object from the main screen. Instead, this screen subscribes to the individual Firestore document corresponding to that task.

```dart
FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection("tasks").doc(taskId).snapshots()
```

This makes sense to me logically: the details page only needs to know about that specific document, so it only subscribes to it to avoid receiving unnecessary updates.

The problem is since the collection-wide subscription for the main screen is still alive while the details screen is open, if the document `/tasks/{taskId}` gets updated, both listeners will trigger. According to the answers in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71634119/does-firestore-on-web-charge-two-reads-for-two-listeners), [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65065038/does-a-client-get-charged-per-listener-for-the-same-firestore-query) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71461991/will-firestores-listen-function-listen-twice-if-it-is-run-twice) question, this means I will get charged for two (duplicate) reads for any single update to that document.

Furthermore, each task can have subtasks. This is reflected in Firestore as a `tasks` subcollection for each task. For example, a nested task could have the path: `/tasks/abc123/tasks/efg875/tasks/aay789`. The main page could show all tasks regardless of nesting by using a collection group query on `"tasks"`. The aforementioned details page also shows the tasks' subtasks by listening to the subcollection. This allows to make complex queries on subtasks (filtering, ordering, etc.), but again the disadvantage is getting duplicate reads for every update to a subtask.

The alternative designs that occur to me are:

- Only keep a single app-wide subscription to the entire set of tasks (be it a flat collection or a collection group query) and do any and all selection, filtering, etc. on the client. For example, the details page of a task would use the same collection-wide subscription and select the appropriate task out of the set every time. Any filtering and ordering of tasks/subtasks would be done on the client.

  - **Advantages:** no duplicate reads, minimizes the Firestore cost.
  - **Disadvantages:** might be more battery intensive for the client, and code would become more complex as I'd have to select the appropriate data out of the entire set of tasks in every situation.
- Cancel the collection-wide subscription when opening the details page and re-start it when going back to the main screen. This means when the details page is open, only updates to that specific task will be received, and without being duplicated as two reads.

  - **Advantages:** no duplicate reads.
  - **Disadvantages:** re-starting the subscription when going back to the main screen means reading all of the documents in the first snapshot, i.e. one read per task, which might actually make the problem worse. Also, it could be quite complicated to code.

Do any of these designs seem the best? Is there another better alternative I'm missing?

Comment: why request a read snapshots()  of every single document when you already requested the snapshots() of the whole collection ?

Comment: @Gwhyyy As explained above: the details page only needs to know about that specific document, so it only subscribes to it to avoid receiving unnecessary updates. In the first of the alternatives design I propose exactly what you are implying, i.e. to rely only on the snapshots of the entire collection. The problem is this complexifies the implementation since each details page has to constantly "sift through" the entire collection snapshot to get the single task document that it wants.

Comment: Moreover I don't request the snapshots of every single document, rather when a details page is opened it starts a subscription to that individual document, and when the page is closed the subscription is also closed. There's at most one details page open at any single moment, so there are no simultaneous single document subscriptions for every document; there is at most one.

Answer (score 4):

Create a `TaskService` or something similar in your app that handles listening to the `FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection("tasks").snapshots()` call, then in your app, subscribe to updates to that service rather than Firebase itself (you can create two `Stream` objects, one for global updates, one for specific updates).

Then, you've only one read going on in your Firebase collection. Everything is handled app side.

Pseudo-code:

```
class TaskService {  
    final List<Task> _tasks = [];
    final StreamController<List<Task>> _signalOnTasks = StreamController.broadcast();
    final StreamController<Task> _signalOnTask = StreamController.broadcast();
    
    get List<Task> allTasks => _tasks;
    Stream<List<Task>> get onTasks => _signalOnTasks.stream;
    Stream<List<Task>> get onTask => _signalOnTask.stream;
    
    void init() {
        FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection("tasks").snapshots().listen(_onData);
    }
    
    void _onData(snapshot) {
        /// get/update our tasks (maybe check for duplicates or whatever)
        _tasks.addAll(snapshot.documents);
        
        /// dispatch our signal streams
        _signalOnTasks.add(snapshot.documents);
        for(final task in snapshot.documents) {
            _signalOnTask.add(task);
        }
    }
}
```

You can make `TaskService` and `InheritedWidget` to get access to it wherever (or use the provider package), the add your listeners to whatever stream you're interested in. You'll need just to check in your listener to `onTask` that it's the correct task before doing anything with it.

Comment: This is one specific design/implementation within the first of the alternatives I suggested. This is certainly an option. However the concerns I have with this kind of approach is overcomplicating the client code and using more battery in the client.

Comment: For the record, if I take this approach I would implement it, seeing as I'm already using Riverpod, as a provider depending on the general collection-wide provider. If anyone is interested in seeing the details I can post a separate answer.

Comment: I'm not sure if keeping an app-wide listener vs a collection listener will make much of a difference in relation to client battery life. As far as I know Firebase handles updates using a websocket that's constantly open, so in either case the network is constantly on. I'm not sure if it creates multiple sockets per listener, or just one though, but even in the case of multiple sockets, I don't think it's making much of a difference